# Asking a user to input their name and outputting their initials in C

Tags: c, cs50

I just wanted to start this off by admitting I'm a complete beginner to coding, and that it's not something that comes intuitively to me.

What I'm trying to do is write a simple program that has the user input their full name, and outputs their initials. The logic I'm trying to follow is that since strings in C are just characters in an array, the characters that should be an initial will come after the '\0' value.

I'm not sure if my problem is a problem of logic or translating that logic into working syntax, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code in full:

```
# include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{

printf ("Please insert your name. \n");
string name = get_string();
//printf ("Your name is %s\n", name);
int x = 0;
char c = name [x];
while (c != '\0')
    {
        x++;
    }
    printf ("%c/n", c);

}
```

I understand it's a complete mess, but again I'm trying to figure out if it's best to just quit, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, welcome! Please don't quit -- I know it can be super hard at first but you'll get it eventually. It looks like you've got a good start here. Keep it up!

Comment: "since strings in C are just characters in an array" Right.  But it's likely that the initials you want will be the *first* characters.  (In my first name `"Steve"` as a C string, the first character is `S`, the character right before the `'\0'` is `e`, and we can't say what's right *after* the `'\0'`.)

Comment: For simplicity, I suggest asking for the person's first, last, and maybe middle names as *separate* strings.  Once you get that working, you can graduate to trying to extract the initials from the full name in a single string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The logic I'm trying to follow is that since strings in C are just characters in an array, the characters that should be an initial will come after the '\0' value.

In C, `\0` denotes the end of a string, so you definitely don't want to be looking for that value.

Let's think about the logic. Someone's initials are probably:

- the first character in the string
- the first character after a space

– i.e. "Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore" -> "APWBD" –

so you'll want to loop over the string, looking for either:

- a space, in which case you'll want to grab the *next* letter, or
- the end of the string (`'\0'`) in which case you'll want to stop.

Edge cases to watch out for:

- what happens if the string is empty?
- what happens if the string ends with a space? (this might not happen if you're guaranteed to get properly formatted input)

Please don't get discouraged – we were all beginners once. This kind of thinking isn't always straightforward, but the answer will come eventually. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for such a helpful answer. It's very difficult not to get discouraged, it feels like everyone else gets it a lot quicker than I do. Thanks again.